# Trigger creation/modification to ensure field equals insertion date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, triggers

I have a table named `Customer` and the column in question is `dbupddate`. This column should contain the datetime of the query that resulted in the record bein inserted.

I have already made a default constraint to `getdate()`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[customer]
(
    [dbupddate] [DATETIME] NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_customer_dbupddate] DEFAULT (GETDATE()),...
```

but this does not prevent someone ofaccidentally entering an irrelevant value.

How can I ensure the column `dbupddate` has the insert datetime?

I guess the answer will contain a trigger. In this case, consider the following already existing trigger, that should not have its effects lost/modified in any way:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[customer_ins_trig]
ON [dbo].[customer]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DELETE u
    FROM transfer_customer_unprocessed u
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted i WHERE i.code = u.code)

    INSERT INTO transfer_customer_unprocessed (code, dbupddate)
        SELECT code, dbupddate
        FROM inserted
END
```

Maybe I could add some lines to that one to suit my needs? Or maybe create another one?

Answer (score 0):

In the procedure which is inserting the data, just don't provide a variable for that column. Granted someone could open SSMS if they have the rights and update it, but you could restrict this with access too.

Additionally, you may want to look into [rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) if this is part of a larger initiative to track changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trigger that does what you want, I think.  Note that the user cannot control content going into InsertDate.

This is a reasonable approach for keeping "last updated" info for your data.  However, @scsimon if you are doing this for other reasons, ROWVERSION is worth exploring, does not require a trigger, and will be much more performant.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Test;
GO

CREATE TABLE Test (
    Id INT NOT NULL ,
    Content NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL ,
    InsertDate DATETIME NULL
);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER TR_Test
ON Test
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    UPDATE t SET t.InsertDate = GETDATE() FROM Test t INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.Id = t.Id;
END;
GO

INSERT Test VALUES (1, '1', NULL), (2, '2', NULL), (3, '3', NULL);
SELECT * FROM Test;
GO

UPDATE Test SET Id = 4, Content = 4 WHERE Id = 1;
UPDATE Test SET Id = 5, Content = 5, InsertDate = NULL WHERE Id = 2;
SELECT * FROM Test;
GO
```